# How to create a list from a CSV file in c#?

Tags: c#, csv

Simply put I have an excel CSV file with a table of Products and a Product Class in my project
I can't seem to extract the data in order to create a list of Product objects from the list in the CSV file.
I realise there is similar questions posted but I cannot seem to get it working correctly.
Can anyone identify the problem ?

```
private static List<Product> ReadProductFile()
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    string curdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string filename = @"C:\Projects\ProductSales\ProductSales\Data\productdetails.csv";

    string[] linesInFile = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    string[] ProductDetails = new string[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < linesInFile.Length; i++)
    {
        string currentLine1 = linesInFile[i];
        ProductDetails = currentLine1.Split(',');
    }

    foreach (var p in ProductDetails)
    {
        Product prod = new Product()
        {
            prod.ID = p. ??
        };
        products.Add(prod);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to loop your `ProductDetails` within your `linesInFile` loop, not after it, among other things

Comment: better read up on the `Split()` Function and also this is not that trivial

Comment: will take that advice onboard.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you provided an example of you .csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < linesInFile.Length; i++)
{
    string currentLine1 = linesInFile[i];
    ProductDetails = currentLine1.Split(',');

    foreach (var p in ProductDetails)
    {
        Product prod = new Product();
        {
            prod.ID = p;
        };
        products.Add(prod);
    }
}
```

Comment: cheers, follow up question, how do I go about extracting the column headings to assign them to the Product class, for example within the foreach loop something like prod.name = p.ProductName ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProductDetails` now is just a number of string values, you need to associate these strings with specific fields. The easiest way is to do it manually, just check the order in the file and do something like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < linesInFile.Length; i++)
{
    string currentLine1 = linesInFile[i];
    ProductDetails = currentLine1.Split(',');

    Product prod = new Product();
    {
        ID = ProductDetails[0];
        Name = ProductDetails[1];
    };
    products.Add(prod);
}
```

I started the loop with `i = 1` because I suppose that the first line will contain captions.
However, if the file format changes, you will have to rewrite this code, so you might want to link properties to columns automatically. If this is the case, have look at `System.Reflection` library.

Comment: Many thanks Nadia, I have to select  king.codes answer as he was first to answer the original question. Your answer is much appreciated.